# Special Core Data fetch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data

My Core Data model has one entity with an attribute called "part". Different objects of this entity can share the same value for "part", meaning they all belong into the same "part". An `NSFetchedResultsController` now can show sections based on these values, taking everything together that belongs together. This works without problems, however I now need the values for "part" for something different now. I would like to fetch only the different values for "part" and display them in a tableView, making sure the same values aren't displayed twice. How can I do this?

I would appreciate some help, Fabian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, figured it out myself. Basically filling an array `partNames` with the informations from my `NSFetchedResultsController`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count]; i++) {
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:i];
    [partNames addObject:[sectionInfo name]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

if (fetchedResultsController_ != nil) {
   return fetchedResultsController_;

}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];



NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"name" cacheName:nil];
aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

[aFetchedResultsController release];
[fetchRequest release];
[sortDescriptor release];
[sortDescriptors release];

NSError *error = nil;
if (![fetchedResultsController_ performFetch:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unerwarteter Fehler %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}

return fetchedResultsController_;
```

}

This will give you all the persons with sort by name and group bu name, removes duplicate values.

-----While creating Fetcgcontroller , have to mention the sectionNameKeyPath ******** -----------